# Domino Server 8.5 link

Tags: lotus-domino

Can someone please send me the download link for Domino Server 8.5 trail version as I want to test Domino Server and Client connectivity.
Since Yesterday I am searching for the appropriate link but could not find the relevant download.
Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Haseena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lotus Domino server trial/demo is currently not available. At least not in a usual (download - install - expire) way.

**Previously Domino was available for download here (who knows, maybe IBM will change this policy tomorrow):**
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsds/index.html

**List of available trials from IBM:**
    http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/byproduct.jsp

**If you must have it your options are either to buy:**
    SMB: http://www.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/dominoexpress/
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsds/buy.html

**or to evaluate it in the cloud:**
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsds/cloud.html
    https://www.lotuslive.com/en/